# Want to have wysiwyg editor in drupal admin

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, admin, drupal-7

I'd like to have `WYSIWYG` editor in drupal admin not in front end. How can I do that? I am using drupal 7.0.

Comment: Question is not programming related, but about configuration and use of Drupal. Belongs on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) of the WYSIWYG modules allow you to specify which forms the WYSIWYG editor gets applied to. You would just need to specify the admin-facing forms.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can configure permissions for different Text formats. My guess is that you could just not allow other users than admin to use the HTML filters. Go to People->Permissions and look under the Filter headline.